# Understanding Json and NSData

Tags: objective-c

We have to create a Jason file to send to server .
The way i found to do that is this :

```
NSDictionary* dic = @{@"Username" :userName,
                          @"Firstname" :firstName,
                          @"Lastname" : lastName,
                          @"Email" : email,
                          @"Password" : pass,
      };
     NSData* json = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:dic options:0 error:nil];
```

I dont really understand why after creating the `dic` , which is already a Json file, I have to use the `NSJSONSerialization` when creating the `NSData` ? ,why not just set the `dic` to the `NSData` ? What exactly this serialization do ?
Also ,why don't create just an `NSString` that will contain this structure ?

Comment: dic is not a json data, it is a NSDictionnary. If you have to send data like you did with the dictionary to the server, you can just use a simple NSString object send it as UTF8 char.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`dic` is an Objective-C dictionary (a collection of key-value pairs) and has nothing to do with JSON. Printing the dictionary might look similar to JSON, but it isn't.

`NSJSONSerialization` creates JSON data from the dictionary. JSON is a text format and is documented e.g. here: http://www.json.org. The JSON data for your dictionary would look like this:

```
{"Firstname":"John","Email":"jon@apple.com","Username":"john","Lastname":"Doe","Password":"topsecret"}
```

That `NSJSONSerialization` creates `NSData` and not `NSString` is just a design decision of the author of that class. You can convert the data to a string with

```
NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:json encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Comment: Thanks a lot . i understand that . but why the dictionary is written like a json with the @ and { at the start ? why not just set values with keys to the dic, and than serialize it to json ?

Comment: @Rant: `@{@"Username" :userName, ...}` is the new "Container Literal" syntax (documented here: http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ObjectiveCLiterals.html). It might look similar to JSON, but it is completely unrelated.